# EditText y ImageButton dentro de un textInputLayout

Tags: android-studio

Trato de colocar el EditText y el ImageButton dentro de un textInputLayout de forma horizontal, en el *Preview* de android aparece bien, pero al momento de ejecutar en el emulador no aparece nada. Lo que quiero hacer es un campo donde el usuario pueda ingresar su fecha de nacimiento y quiero agregarle el ImageButton para que al presionar ahí se abra un calendario, y no quiero cambiar de contenedor ya que con el textInputLayout puedo lograr que el textHint se vaya a la parte superior quedando como un titulo (Fecha de Nacimiento).

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        style="@style/textInputLayoutOutlinedBoxDense">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".9"
            android:hint="Fecha de Nacimiento"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".1"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Donde tenes este layout o dónde lo usas?

Comment: lo tengo en un _android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout_

Comment: Me parece que necesitas un Layout en el medio que haga de GroupParent. ConstraintLayout o RelativeLayout como para posicionar los elementos. (Adentro del Coordinator, y contenientdo al TextInputLayout)

Comment: Tambien hice eso, coloque un linearLayout para almacenar el editText y el ImageView de manera horizontal, pero surge un problema y es que en el textInputLayout se puede habilitar el contador de caracteres(_countEnable_), y ese contador queda arriba del editText cuando deberia quedar abajo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incluí el LinearLayout entre el `Coordinator` y el `TextInputLayout`, movíe el `ImageButton` al `LinearLayout` y acomodé el layout.
Al botón por ahí te conviene wrapearlo en un `FrameLayout` y darle un tamaño específico.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="90"
            app:counterEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Fecha de Nacimiento"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Y queda de esta forma:

[image: Layout]

**II) Otra opción** es usar el `drawableRight` del `TextInputEditText`.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/ti"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:counterEnabled="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/tied"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/calendario"
                android:drawablePadding="5dp"
                android:hint="Fecha de Nacimiento"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Y en el `onCreate()` del `Activity`

```
tied = findViewById(R.id.tied);

tied.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

           final int DRAWABLE_RIGHT = 2;

           if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
               if(event.getRawX() >= (tied.getRight() - tied.getCompoundDrawables()[DRAWABLE_RIGHT].getBounds().width())) {

                   Log.d(TAG, "Click en imagen"); // Lo que acciona el click

                   return true;
               }
           }
           return false;
       }
});
```

[image: TextInputLayout con drawableRight]

Nota: La imagen es de 30 x 30 px. Para cambiar el tamaño hay que cambiar el tamaño del png.